# Autosave HandsOnTable data to JSON

Tags: php, jquery, handsontable

I'm working with HandsOnTable and trying to implement saving to a JSON file on the server.

This is how the page looks like:

```
<div id="example1" class="handsontable"></div>
<button name="save">Guardar</button>
```

And the jQuery:

```
var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');

$parent.find('button[name=save]').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "save.json",
    data: {"data": handsontable.getData()}, //returns all cells' data
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (res) {
      if (res.result === 'ok') {
        $console.text('Data saved!');
      }
      else {
        $console.text('Save error');
      }
    },
    error: function () {
      $console.text('Save error.');
    }
  });
});
```

I'm also working on a PHP script to write all cells' data above to a JSON file, it should be called whenever the user clicks the save button. This how it looks now:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){

    $myFile = "testFile.json";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "Floppy Jalopy\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
};

?>
```

My question is how do I send all the cell's data to the PHP variable $stringData?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've got same thing what you want to do. I've implemented this with Ajax and auto-complete feature. I'm putting new data directly into load.json file so every time load button pressed user gets new data. My code goes following way...

**index.html**

```
<script data-jsfiddle="example">
var $console = $("#example1console");
        var data = [ [] ];
        var autosaveNotification;

            $('#example').handsontable({
              data: data,
              minSpareRows: 1,
              minSpareCols: 1,
              colHeaders: true,
              rowHeaders: true, 
              autoWrapRow: true,
              currentRowClassName: 'currentRow',
              currentColClassName: 'currentCol',              
              contextMenu: { items: {
                                      "row_above": {},
                                      "row_below": {},
                                      "hsep1": "---------",
                                      "col_left": {},
                                      "col_right": {},
                                      "hsep2": "---------",
                                      "remove_row": {},
                                      "remove_col": {}
                                      }
                            },

              afterChange: function (change, source) 
                            {
                                if (source === 'loadData') {
                                  return; //don't save this change
                                }
                                if ($('input[name=autosave]').is(':checked')) 
                                {
                                  clearTimeout(autosaveNotification);

                                    $.ajax({
                                    url: "saveData.php",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: {"data": handsontable.getData()}, //returns all cells' data
                                    complete: function (data) {
                                          $console.text('Autosaved (' + change.length + ' cell' + (change.length > 1 ? 's' : '') + ')');
                                          autosaveNotification = setTimeout(function () {
                                            $console.text('Changes will be autosaved');
                                          }, 1000);
                                        }
                                  });
                                }
                           }
            });     
        </script>
```

**saveData.php**

```
<?php 

$file = 'json\load.json'; 

file_put_contents($file, ""); // Erase file content because we need to use this content for loading.

    foreach ($_POST['data'] as $change) 
    {       
        file_put_contents($file, json_encode($change) . ",", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }

// remove last comma from data...
$fileHandle = fopen($file, 'r+') or die("can't open file");
$stat = fstat($fileHandle);
ftruncate($fileHandle, $stat['size']-1);
fclose($fileHandle);


// Append rest of syntax to file content so when press load next time we got ready new data...
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$newData = "{ \"data\": [ " . $current . " ] }"; 
file_put_contents($file, $newData);

// success json response...
$out = array('result' => 'ok');
echo json_encode($out); 

?>
```

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

1. 'url: "save.json",' in ajax does not make sense, url should be the place where the posted data is proceeded in PHP.
2. data: {"data": handsontable.getData()}, (i am not sure about the format in handsontable.getData())... you may have to make it json formatted string before posting it.
3. in php code, try '$stringData = $_POST["data"];' or try to use json_encode to make json formatted string before saving it into file.

Comment: Hi, I replaced "save.json" by "escreve.php". PHP is creating an empty "testFile.json". So, the script is being executed but the data from handsontable isn't being sent. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, this worked for me:
<?php
 
 $myFile = "testFile.json";
 $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
 $stringData = $_POST['data'];
 $stringData='{  "data":'.json_encode($stringData).'}';
 fwrite($fh, $stringData);
 fclose($fh);

?>